# Where to change GRASS GIS wxGUI language?

Tags: grass-gis

I use GRASS 6.4.2 on Russian version of Windows 7 x64. As I start wxGUI it is shown in Russian. But I don't like its translation and want to work with English interface. I have no clues how to solve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have recently added a language selector in the graphical interface. This is
currently under testing in GRASS 6.4.3.
For now, you can upgrade to GRASS 6.4.3svn but installing this version:

http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass64/

In the wxGUI:

Settings --> Preferences --> Appearance --> Language Settings

It should solve your problem.

Comment: Just FYI: there are still some issues which we probably solved a few hours ago :) So all should be then available in the upcoming GRASS GIS 6.4.3.