# Changing GRASS language within QGIS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, internationalization

I use GRASS plugin inside QGIS on Japanese version of windows 7 x64. As I start GRASS tools, all the content show in English but when I try to execute a tool, tools option displays in Japanese language. I want to change all the tool options in to English and have no clues how to solve it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try to set the language in both QGIS and GRASS.

For [QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/26458/1297): Settings > Options > Locale > place checkmark beside *Override system local*.

For [GRASS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/30928/1297): Launch the GRASS GUI > Settings > Preferences > Appearance > Language Settings.

Comment: Thanks. I already did that but doesn`t help. My QGIS envirnoment already in English. If you see my screenshot, only the options appear in Japanese other all the things in English

Comment: @Kava did you change language in grass too?

Comment: Hi SaultDon, no still couldn't do it. Hope you have seen my screenshot. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for above miss-understanding. Yes, I changed in both GRASS and QGIS but it doesn't change in GRASS tool interface. still same as above screenshot

Comment: @Kava Than maybe you have to change the language at the Operating System level if possible.